# Problem with Chrome rendering some Latex

Tags: bug, mathjax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Formula layout bug](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/2250/formula-layout-bug)

Chrome has been rendering some Latex badly on my computer lately. I've taken a screenshot of what it looks like, which I found on [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71698/how-do-i-prove-that-cos-frac2-pi7-notin-mathbbq),

[image: screenshot]

(The equation $x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$ should appear at the bottom of the post, not at the top!)

This isn't the first time I've seen this problem. I've had it when I have been posting my own posts. I got around it be putting the 'tex on a new line, if I remember correctly.

I have switched browsers to both Opera and Firefox and I did not have a similar problem. I am using Chrome 14.0.835.202 on Mac OS X 10.6.7.

What may or may not be related is a similar problem I have had, which is where the posts "continue" to the right of where they should stop, and appear under the stuff on the right (the "Visit Meta" and text below it in the screenshot). I don't have a screenshot of this as I can't get it to happen again, so it may not be a problem anymore, but I thought I'd better mention it anyway...

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/2250/856